# Creating my own Menu Component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I'm creating a "Menu" component that I call on every pages and it shows correctly but I can't get it working.
I can't navigate as easily as I did in my Login page: Button with OnPress Event and a Call to one function with /if correct logins/ execute:  `this.props.navigation.navigate("Accueil")`

So... I taught that it could be the same and on my component "Menu" I tried to call the same code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.menu_item_selected,styles.menu_item]} onPress={() => nav("Home")}>
   <FontAwesome name="home" size={40} color="#fff"/>
   <Text style={styles.menu_text}>Home</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.menu_item}  onPress={() => nav("Datas")}>
   <FontAwesome name="user" size={40} color="#fff"/>
   <Text style={styles.menu_text}>Datas</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But it doesn't work, it crashes on button press.

Here is my Navigation file:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'

import Login from '../Components/Login'
import Menu from '../Components/Menu'
import Home from '../Components/Home'
import Datas from '../Components/Datas'

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  Home:{
    screen: Home
  },
  Datas:{
    screen: Datas
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(SearchStackNavigator)
```

I tried to use props, but didn't worked too.

More info:

- The usage of my "Menu" component is like class Menu extand React.Component /some code/ and export default Menu then `<Menu/>` on my pages.
- My tries with props looked like    `_nav(page){
  this.props.navigation.navigate(page)
  }` on pages like "Home" and "Datas" at the top before the "render(){return(" part. Then `const { nav } = this.props` in my "Menu" component and something like `onPress={() => nav("Donnees")}` on my menu buttons.

Any ideas? Or sample codes? I couldn't find any custom menu sample that fill my needs

Comment: How do you use this "Menu" component?, and how are you passing the navigation props to it? and please add the error you are receiving.

Comment: @Charlie Sorry I've modified my code many times, I mostly received "undefined is not an object" or "Application has not been registered". The usage of my "Menu" component is like class Menu extand React.Component /some code/ and export default Menu then `<Menu/>` on my pages. My tries with props looked like    _`nav(page){
    this.props.navigation.navigate(page)
  }` on pages like "Home" and "Datas" at the top before the "render(){return(" part. Then `const { nav } = this.props` in my "Menu" component and something like `onPress={() => nav("Donnees")}` on my menu buttons.

Comment: @Sch have you tried [binding](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) the nav function? Something like this `onPress={nav.bind(this, "Home")}`

Comment: @jpetty I got an error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nav.bind')" while using `onPress={nav.bind(this, "Home")}`. I also tried to add this to my previous code: `onPress={() => this.nav("Home")}` but I get "_this.nav is not a function (In '_this.nav("Home")','_this.nav' is undefined)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the navigation prop to your Menu component like this(Assuming you are using it in a Screen declared in your Navigation config):

```
<Menu navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

with that your Menu component will have access to navigation prop

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Datas');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this evening, I'll tell you if it worked

Comment: It works, thanks! Now i'm using `<Menu navigation={this.props.navigation} />`  and on my Menu buttons `onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Datas');}}`